# Adding data into hash table using linear probing

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashtable

Suppose, I have a hash table of size 10 and I want to insert following data into it

```
1,5,7,87,47,27,97,34,89,10
```

My hash function is : `key % 10`.

So when I use the above function, what should I do if the index obtained after linear probing (simply placing the data in the next empty index) is greater than the table size.

i.e. To add `97` to the table

```
 97 % 10 == 7 (hash collision)
```

To resolve it I will look at `8th` index which is also packed, so I will look at `9th` index which is also packed now next up is 10(but size is from 0 - 9), how should I resolve it?Should I move to 0? what is the procedure?

Comment: Yes, move to 0 (there is still room, and using the same rule during a search will work).

Comment: Needless to say, it is foolish to let the table fill to 100%

Comment: @RBarryYoung: not true - both separate chaining (your "lockaside lists") and open addressing aka closed hashing (probing, whether linear, quadratic, random...) are still very popular.  C++ only provides separate chaining in the Standard Library, but python dicts use open addressing with pseudo-random probing (in the most common CPython implementation at least),  And for C++ there are a lot of extremely fast open addressing implementations - Folly F14, abseil, robinhood etc..  Open addressing has better cache utilisation.  "becomes irresolvable when the table fills up"  - you resize/rehash.